# concatenate initialize variable to zero in c++

Tags: c++, concatenation

Does anyone know the reason why strncat cannot concatenate char initialize to zero? code below

```
int main()
{
uint8 uibuffer[4] = {0};
uint8 txbuffer[10] = "ab";
uint8 rxbuffer[4] = "cde";

strncat((char*)txbuffer,(char*)uibuffer, 4);
strncat((char*)txbuffer,(char*)rxbuffer, 4);
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(txbuffer); i += 1)
{
    cout << (int(txbuffer[i]))<<" : "<< char(int(txbuffer[i]))<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

the output now is

```
97 : a
98 : b
99 : c
100 : d
101 : e
0 : 
0 : 
0 : 
0 : 
0 :
```

the desired output would be

```
97 : a
98 : b
0 : 
0 : 
0 : 
0 :    
99 : c
100 : d
101 : e 
0 :
```

Comment: strncat stops copying when it encounters a `\0` and a string of the form "ab" actually has one of those at its end. You need a custom function to achieve this.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do this with std::string?

Comment: the reason behind is because im concatenating char arrays and integers that need to be converted to char arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [memcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy), strings in C end at the first 0 character.

Comment: memcpy() does not necessarily work either, since the characters beyond the `\0` may end up set as junk by the compiler.

Comment: @scorpiodawg: You mean the remaining 7 uint8s in txbuffer? Those can't have a junk value.